# Javascript str.replace with variables

Tags: javascript, variables, replace

I have found a short script which finds a line with a certain phrase in it and replaces the whole line with a new line. However I can't work out how to include a variable where it says '#RemoveMe' in the str.replace. (I want to include the variable 'start' which is passed in by the function's trigger, to make --> (/^.*start.*$/mg, ""))

Any help appreciated...

```
        var str = 'line1\n'+
          'line2\n'+
          '#RemoveMe line3\n'+
          'line4';

        var test = str.replace(/^.*#RemoveMe.*$/mg, "");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a limitation of the inline regular expression notation.

If you use `new RegExp()` you can pass the expression as a string.

```
var find = "start";
var regexp = new RegExp("^.*" + find + ".*$", "mg"); // note: no delimiters
str.replace(regexp, "");
```

Comment: If you need to escape the value (to make sure the user can actually use `.`'s etc.), you can use [`PHPJS`'s version of `preg_quote`](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/)

Comment: There is never a (good) reason to allow user input in a regular expression.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen negative. user filtering

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for text filtering. Anything more complex is probably silly. Wildcards go a long way.

Comment: Thank-you, exact answer and extremely quick!  :)